# Automatically closing VLC player when video complete?

Tags: java, video, vlcj

So I'm using VLCJ and the VLC player for java to play a video when I run my program. Problem is, the video player only closes when the user clicks the "x" button. Is there a way to close it automatically when the video ends?

Thanks!

If it helps, here's my code:

```
//////Main class:

package switchAndAnim;

import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class Start {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //location of vlc files, media file
        new MediaPlayer("vlc-2.0.2", "ryankilp2.wmv").run();
    }

}

///////MediaPlayer class:
package switchAndAnim;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;

public class MediaPlayer {
private JFrame ourFrame = new JFrame();

    private EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent ourMediaPlayer;

    private String mediaPath = "";

    MediaPlayer(String vlcPath,String mediaURL)
    {
        this.mediaPath = mediaURL;

        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), vlcPath);

        ourMediaPlayer = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();

        ourFrame.setContentPane(ourMediaPlayer);

        ourFrame.setSize(640,480);

        ourFrame.setVisible(true);

        ourFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    public void run()
    {
        ourMediaPlayer.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(mediaPath);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The media player has all sorts of events you can listen for, one of them being the "finished" event that fires when the end of the video is reached.

```
ourMediaPlayer = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent() {
    public void finished(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        ourMediaPlayer.release(); // In practice, this line is optional
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

I used System.exit() since your question set `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`, but equally you could hide or dispose the frame instead depending on your use case.